# Populating struct after module reload

Tags: c++, module, dlopen

Folks, suppose the following code snippet:

```
struct some_type st[] = {
"foo",
"bar",
//more stuff...
};
```

The actual struct is a bit more complex than that but I don't it it matter.

This code is part of a module, loaded with `dlopen` (with `RTLD_LAZY` as the only flag). When this module is first loaded, everything is good, and the struct is populated sucessfuly. However when I unload this module (with `dlclose`) and load it again, this struct come up empty. It is set in global scope.

How can I make it get repopulated after reloading the module?

Comment: Your code isn't initializing a struct, it's initializing an array of structs. Is this array initialization being done at file-level scope? If so, then the linker likely put it in the data segment which is only required to be run once when the object is first placed in memory. If you unload the module and then reload it, the loader may just reuse the already-loaded object in which case the data segment won't be touched. How do you know the struct is "empty" when you load the module a second time?

Comment: Yes, file level. I know it is empty because if I try to print the strings I get a segfault (running the same function that loaded it successfuly in the first time). Is there a way to force the reloading of the data segment?